# How to get the intersection between two partitions while keeping most inclusive groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

```r
 library(tidyverse)
 
 df <- tibble(labels= paste0("specimen", 1:158),
              part1= rep(c(1:12), c(6, 22, 11, 24, 6, 5, 3, 13, 7, 16, 42, 3)),
              part2= rep(c(1:13), c(2, 4, 1, 11, 10, 11, 2, 22, 6, 5, 3, 78, 3)))
 df %>% 
   group_by(part1, part2) %>%
   mutate(union= cur_group_id())
#> # A tibble: 158 × 4
#> # Groups:   part1, part2 [16]
#>    labels     part1 part2 union
#>    <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 specimen1      1     1     1
#>  2 specimen2      1     1     1
#>  3 specimen3      1     2     2
#>  4 specimen4      1     2     2
#>  5 specimen5      1     2     2
#>  6 specimen6      1     2     2
#>  7 specimen7      2     3     3
#>  8 specimen8      2     4     4
#>  9 specimen9      2     4     4
#> 10 specimen10     2     4     4
#> # ℹ 148 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I have a few datasets like this one and i want to get the "union" and the "intersection" between partitions 1 and 2. To get the "union" is quite simple and i did it by using `cur_group_id()`. The problem is with the "intersection", which i want it to be the most inclusive group between part1 and part2. I've tried some solutions using `if_else()` and they work in some cases, but not all of them, since sometimes the most inclusive group lies within part1 and sometimes in part2, which makes it harder to get into a single solution.

For example: In part1, "2" corresponds to "3", "4" and "5" on part2. Thus, for my purposes, "2" is the most inclusive group, since it contains "3", "4" and "5". Same goes for "12" in part2, which corresponds to "8", "9", "10" and "11" on part1.

Although i prefer a solution using `dplyr`, any solutions are welcome!

Edit:

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiUVJ.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "most inclusive group" - can you say more?

Comment: For example: In part1, "2" corresponds to "3", "4" and "5" on part2. Thus, for my purposes, "2" is the most inclusive group, since it contains "3", "4" and "5"

Comment: Perhaps `df |> distinct(part1, part2) |>  add_count(part1, name = "part1_n") |> add_count(part2, name = "part2_n")`?

Comment: Could you pleased show what values you are expecting for each row in the data you  have?  "Union" is basically the  number assigned to the combination.  It's not reall clear to me what "intersection" would be, but that's because I guess I am thinking of sets.

Comment: Basically "intersection" would have the same dimension of the other columns but it would have 9 groups as in mutate(intersection= rep(c(1:7, 12, 13), c(6, 22, 11, 24, 6, 5, 3, 78, 3)))

Comment: I don't understand that mutate, that would produce the same vector in each row.

Comment: So the first 78 values are equal to part1 and the rest are equal to part2?  Why not just write that?

Comment: Because i have several pairwise combinations to look at and i need it to fit every type of comparisons between partitions of different sizes

Answer (score 0):

```
df |>
  count(part1, part2) |>
  add_count(part1, name = "part1_n") |>
  add_count(part2, name = "part2_n") |>
  filter(part1_n == max(part1_n) | part2_n == max(part2_n))
```

Output shows the rows in the "most inclusive" for part1 and part2:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  part1 part2     n part1_n part2_n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <int>   <int>
1     2     3     1       3       1
2     2     4    11       3       1
3     2     5    10       3       1
4     8    12    13       1       4
5     9    12     7       1       4
6    10    12    16       1       4
7    11    12    42       1       4
```

Comment: Interesting but i need a column with the same dimension as the part1/part2 and union columns

Comment: I still don’t understand what your desired output is.